# How to implement CallKit while app is in Background or Kill in quickblox?

Tags: swift, quickblox, q-municate

In quickblox demo code I found that CallKit incoming call screen is appear when app is active, but nothing happen except notification while doing call when recipient app is in background or kill.

I am familiar with Twilio and Sinch and I know they provides methods which works at the time of call when app is in background or kill. Is there any extra set up I need to do i.e VOIP or anything else ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.